# Returning a variable name from an array in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I want to append the value as $EC5 in my newlist in shell script. However, it is currently storing value as 11 in newlist array.

```
EC2=0
EC3=0
EC4=0
EC5=11
return_codes=( $EC2 $EC3 $EC4 $EC5)
newlist=()

for i in "${return_codes[@]}";
do
    if [[ $i -ne 0 ]]
        then
            newlist+=($i)
    fi
done
```

Kindly Help.

Comment: `$EC5` *is* `11`. Or do you mean you want to store the string `EC5` itself? Leave out the `$` then. When you run `return_codes=( $EC2 $EC3 $EC4 $EC5 )`, that does `return_codes=( 0 0 0 11 )`; the place where each of those numbers originally came from is lost.

Comment: There are no arrays in POSIX `[shell]` so you should add the proper tag for the shell you are using. `[bash]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the variable's value, you can store its name and look that up:

```
EC2=0
EC3=0
EC4=0
EC5=11
return_codes=( EC2 EC3 EC4 EC5)
newlist=()

for i in "${return_codes[@]}";
do
    if [[ ${!i} -ne 0 ]]
        then
            newlist+=($i)
    fi
done
```